# Make another content list as content file of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have page I want to display the page in different style (not as the content.php file ) so now I made copy the content.php file and just modified it. I want to display only for one page and other pages should display like content.php . So how can I change the index page to display the particular as new content-list page. My page name is News and it should be display like content-list.php.

Answer (score 1):

For display indiviual page you have to make a Template for that page and from 
Dashboard-->Pages open the page where you want to display that template, on right hand side you have seen TAMPLATE-->DEFAULT TEMPLATE, select template you have created...

Syntax for new template

```
<?php 
/*Template Name:abc
*/
?>

<?php get_header();?>
<!--------------------------------------->
CONTENT FOR PAGE
<!--------------------------------------->
<?php get_Footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about which file you're referring to as `content.php`

> I have page i want display the page in different style

So, if you want to display a page with a different style, you should have a look at [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

You can create another page template, use custom files like header-{name}.php and footer-{name}.php and use [get_header()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) and [get_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) with the appropriate arguments(the {name} you mentionned to call these files.

Comment: i am talking about Custom Post Types display. i hAve to include a custom post type file. in archive.php.